# A Gaussian Sequence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

$W_1,W_2,\ldots$ are independent Gaussian random variables with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2>0$. Define the sequence $(X_n:n\ge 0)$ recursively by $X_0=0$ and: $X_{k+1}=\frac{X_k+W_k}{2}$. Determine in which ones of the four senses, a.s,m.s,p. and d., the sequence $(X_n)$ converges.

One can see that: $X_k=\sum_{m=1}^{k-1}W_m\cdot (\frac{1}{2})^{m-(k-1)}$.
As far as I can tell for m.s. there's this property that $X_n\to X$ as $n\to \infty$ in the m.s. sense then: $\lim_{k\to\infty}E[X_k]=E[X]\ \ \ \lim_{k\to \infty}E[X_k^2]=E[X^2]$.
After some calculations if $\lim_{k\to \infty} E[X_k]=\lim E[X_{k-1}]/2+\lim E[W_{k-1}]/2$, so I get that: $\lim E[X_k]=0$, and $\lim_{k\to \infty} E[X_k^2]=\lim [E[X_{k-1}^2]/4+E[X_{k-1}W_{k-1}]+E[W_{k-1}^2]/4]$, now if I am not mistaken $W_k$ and $X_k$ are independent, so $E[X_{k-1}W_{k-1}]=E[X_{k-1}]E[W_{k-1}]=0$, so I get that: $\lim_{k\to \infty} E[X_k^2]=\sigma^2/3$, so for $X=W$ where $W$ is a Gaussian random variable with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2>0$ I get that there's no m.s. convergence.
Am I right here?
How about the other three senses?
I appreciate your help!

Comment: You should explicit what the abbreviations a.s./m.s./p./d. stand for. Otherwise, since $X_0 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,0)$, $W_k \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2) \;\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lambda_1\mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2) + \lambda_2\mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2) \sim \mathcal{N}(\lambda_1\mu_1+\lambda_2\mu_2, \lambda_1^2\sigma_1^2+\lambda_2^2\sigma_2^2)$ due to the property of stability of the normal law), you have $X_n \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{3}(1-4^{-n})\right)$ and $X_\infty \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2/3)$.